# Refreshing WPF Custom Control, using dummy property

Tags: wpf, properties, refresh

I have a custom control in WPF, need to refresh it when network data available.
It checks status in a timer and when needs refresh calls RefreshMe();
Since there is not direct refresh method, I used a dummy property and added **FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender** to it.

But it doesn't always work.

```
void RefreshMe()
{
   RefreshDummyCounter++;
}

public int RefreshDummyCounter
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(RefreshDummyCounterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RefreshDummyCounterProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RefreshDummyCounter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RefreshDummyCounterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RefreshDummyCounter", typeof(int), typeof(FastListView), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender|FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));
```